# YouTube API - analytics v 1 report returning 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: c#-4.0, google-analytics, youtube-analytics

Hi All i'm having an application which pulls YouTube analytics data but it is not working from sometime. The details are below with code

```
for (int ISOCountryCode = 0; ISOCountryCode < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; ISOCountryCode++)
                {
                    //validation to check if date is null
                    string strdimensions = "day";
                    string strmetrics = "views,comments,favoritesAdded,favoritesRemoved,likes,dislikes,shares,estimatedMinutesWatched,averageViewDuration,averageViewPercentage,annotationClickThroughRate,annotationCloseRate,subscribersGained,subscribersLost,uniques";
                    string strstartdate = Convert.ToDateTime(WeekStartDate).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
                    string strenddate = Convert.ToDateTime(WeekEndDate).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");

                    string DownloadURL = string.Format("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/analytics/v1/reports?ids=channel==" + ChannelID + "&start-date=" + strstartdate + "&end-date=" + strenddate + "&metrics=" + strmetrics + "&key=KE9gM-4_tgmVw3L3QaMSeR-G4X5vr7tA&access_token=" + token + "&dimensions=" + strdimensions + "&alt=csv&filters=country==" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[ISOCountryCode]["ISOCode"].ToString());
                    urlDownload.Download(DownloadURL, "Z:\\InsightData\\ChannelData\\UnZipFilesFldr\\" + ChannelID + "_world_" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[ISOCountryCode]["ISOCode"].ToString() + ".csv");

                    strdimensions = "day,operatingSystem,deviceType";
                    strmetrics = "estimatedMinutesWatched,views";

                    DownloadURL = string.Format("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/analytics/v1/reports?ids=channel=={2}&start-date=" + strstartdate + "&end-date=" + strenddate + "&metrics=" + strmetrics + "&key=KE9gM-4_tgmVw3L3QaMSeR-G4X5vr7tA&access_token={0}&dimensions=" + strdimensions + "&alt=csv&filters=country=={1}", token, ds.Tables[0].Rows[ISOCountryCode]["ISOCode"].ToString(), ChannelID);
                    urlDownload.Download(DownloadURL, "Z:\\InsightData\\ChannelData\\UnZipFilesFldr\\" + ChannelID + "_world-device_" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[ISOCountryCode]["ISOCode"].ToString() + ".csv");

                    strdimensions = "day,operatingSystem,deviceType";
                    strmetrics = "estimatedMinutesWatched,views";

                    DownloadURL = string.Format("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/analytics/v1/reports?ids=channel=={2}&start-date=" + strstartdate + "&end-date=" + strenddate + "&metrics=" + strmetrics + "&key=KE9gM-4_tgmVw3L3QaMSeR-G4X5vr7tA&access_token={0}&dimensions=" + strdimensions + "&alt=csv&filters=country=={1}", token, ds.Tables[0].Rows[ISOCountryCode]["ISOCode"].ToString(), ChannelID);
                    urlDownload.Download(DownloadURL, "Z:\\InsightData\\ChannelData\\UnZipFilesFldr\\" + ChannelID + "_world-deviceType_" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[ISOCountryCode]["ISOCode"].ToString() + ".csv");
                }

The Code in the urlDownload.Download is :-

HttpWebRequest wr = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(strURLFileandPath);
                HttpWebResponse ws = (HttpWebResponse)wr.GetResponse();
                Stream str = ws.GetResponseStream(); - > Line Of Error
```

On the last line where it asks for the response stream it errors out and says "500 Internal Server Error"

Comment: Is there no one who can help me on the issue?

Comment: If You need more info then let me know?

Comment: I think is is safe to say there is **ZERO** support for the youtube API. As a developer, i don't want to put up with this mess. This turns me away from developing cool apps for youtube. It will hurt them in the long run. Let me see what i can find on your issue.

Comment: Did you found anything Elite? Or anyone else who can help?

Comment: I have been looking for a while, but i cant find anything for C#. PHP was not really documented either @Prasoon

Comment: Thanks Elite for your precious time.